Untitled blank loading page after starting server in Svelte
I'm new to Svelte and I'm just trying to run a Svelte project that should be working just fine. I followed the instructions of the repository, installing packages with pnpm i, and then when starting the server with pnpm dev --open i get these logs in the console:
  VITE v5.2.8  ready in 739 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
  ➜  Network: use --host to expose
  ➜  press h + enter to show help

However in the browser I just see an Untitled blank page that loads without end. Inspecting the page, the elements it is just a completely blank HTML page, and there are no console logs neither network requests going on.

If i try to build the app, the build seems to happen successfully, but when I press to open the build locally I get the same, a blank loading page and nothing more. I didn't modify any of the code, and I believe it is supposed to work as it is. Any experiences with any similar situation?
